# Background task Tomcat JEE

Tags: java, hibernate, asynchronous, tomcat7, java-ee-8

I am desperately trying to execute a background task in a JEE 8 application running on Tomcat 7.
I want the user to send a request (through a Jersey REST API) and to receive immediately a response whilst the server process a long task.

I've read tones of articles, but none seems to do the trick right...

Here is what I've got so far

```
public abstract class AbstractService<T extends Entity> {

    private final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    [...]

    public void executeAsync(Entity entity) {
        es.execute(() -> {
           // Do some eavy stuffs on the entity
           em.persist(entity);
        });
    }
}

public class PMyEntityService extends AbstractService<MyEntity> {
[...]
}
```

That doesn't work because the `ExecutorService` doesn't preserve the context, so my injection isn't available inside the child Threads.

So I did like that

```
public abstract class AbstractService<T extends Entity> {

    private final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    [...]

    public void executeAsync(Entity entity) {
        es.execute(() -> {
           EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
           this.em = emf.createEntityManager();
           // Do some eavy stuffs on the entity
           em.persist(entity);
           emf.close();
        });
    }
}

public class MyEntityService extends AbstractService<MyEntity> {
[...]
}
```

Which seems to work well at the first sight, but after many tries, it appears that if I start many simultaneous requests, many `ExecutorService` are creating, leading to many `EntityManagerFactory`, leading to an overload of connexions to the database.

So I tried to put the `ExecutorService` as `static`, which doen't work either.

So I've created a new `@ApplicationScoped` class with only one static field that is an `ExecutorService`... the database connection is still overflowed.

I tried to implement some `ManagedExecutorService` but they are only available in javaee-web-api v6.0 while I'm using v8.0.1

I've tried to implement a `WorkManager`, didn't work either.

I've put my `EntityManagerFactory` as static in an `@ApplicationScoped` class, fail again.
...

Please help !

Comment: The [duplicate] does not answer my question. I do not want schedule tasks.

Comment: You asked how to “execute a background task”. The concepts [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48855184/642706) still apply: Write a class implementing the two methods defined in `ServletContextListener`. In the `contextInitialized` method, establish your executor service, cached as a context attribute. Retrieve that executor service via the context attribute when your servlet needs to run a task on a background thread. In the `contextDestroyed` method, shutdown the executor service.